# How to color only portion of text of ListBox items using IValue converter in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

Say I have a collection of names as

```
arMahesh Nagar    
arPriyank arSark
```

What I need is that, by using IValue converter I want to color only say `'ar' s`

The output should be some what (if put in HTML..but I am working in WPF.So just to demonstrate my requirement)

```
Mahesh Nag<font color='blue'>ar</font>
Priyanka S<font color='blue'>ar</font>k<font color='blue'>ar</font>
```

At present my IValue converter is highlighting the complete text (rather I don't know how to do this)

```
public class HighlightNames : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            SolidColorBrush _scb = new SolidColorBrush();

            var personName = ((Person)value).PersonName;

            //I know the below is wrong
            if(personName.StartsWith("N")) _scb = Brushes.DarkGoldenrod;
            else _scb = Brushes.Aqua;
            return _scb;


        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

And Xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Android Search in WPF" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HighlightNames x:Key="colorrootnode"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>        
        <ListBox 
            x:Name="lstNames" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="207" Margin="37,64,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding PersonName}"
                               Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource colorrootnode}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit**
The IValueConverter is now

```
namespace WpfApplication1.Converters
{
    public class HighlightNames : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var personName = value.ToString();// ((Person)value).PersonName;

            var textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

            List<string> lstNames = new List<string>();
            lstNames.Add(personName);

            string toSearch = "ar";

            string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { " " };
            string matchedStrings = "";

            foreach (var l in lstNames)
            {
                if (l.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None)

                          .Any(i => i.StartsWith(toSearch)))
                {
                    matchedStrings = l;
                }
            }

            var s1 = matchedStrings.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            var firstPart = s1[0];
            var secondPart = s1[1];
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(firstPart));
            Run run = new Run(secondPart);
            run.Background = Brushes.Aqua; ;
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
            return textBlock;


        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And Xaml is

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"        
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Android Search in WPF" Height="350" Width="525"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Converters">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HighlightNames x:Key="colorrootnode"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>        
        <ListBox 
            x:Name="lstNames" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
            Height="207" Margin="37,64,0,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                   
                    <ContentControl Content="{Binding PersonName, Converter={StaticResource colorrootnode}}">
                    </ContentControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The output is

[image]

But it should highlight only the 'ar's from the first and last names if any one is matched.

So in the first case only the starting **ar** of **arMahesh Nagar** will be highlighted.

For case 2, **arPriyank arSark**, only both the 'ar''s will be highlighted.

Since they search string starts with.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for a MVVM compliant solution or not?

Comment: yes, it should satisfy MVVM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a MVVM solution I suggest to consider that a string is a collection of chars. You can consider string and chars as models, so you have to wrap them with a viewmodel. I do not know your whole project so I propose just a sample.
Let's see the code starting from XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="HighlightableSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HighlightableSample"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:BoolBrushConverter x:Key="BoolBrushConverter" />
        <local:BoolFontWeightConverter x:Key="BoolFontWeightConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>


    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="4" Text="{Binding SearchFor, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding HlStrings}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneTime}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SourceChar, Mode=OneWay}"
                               Background="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolBrushConverter}}"
                               FontWeight="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BoolFontWeightConverter}}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

The Window's `DataContext` is set with a new instance of a `MainViewModel` class:

```
public class MainViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    private string searchFor;
    private ObservableCollection<HighlightableString> hlStrings =
        new ObservableCollection<HighlightableString>();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        hlStrings.Add(new HighlightableString("arMahesh Nagar"));
        hlStrings.Add(new HighlightableString("arPriyank arSark"));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<HighlightableString> HlStrings
    {
        get
        {
            return hlStrings;
        }
    }

    public string SearchFor
    {
        get
        {
            return searchFor;
        }
        set
        {
            searchFor = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchFor");

            foreach (HighlightableString hls in hlStrings)
            {
                hls.Highlight(searchFor);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`NotifyPropertyChangedImpl` is a base class which just implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.
As I told, now we need a ViewModel for the string. I called it `HighlightableString`:

```
public class HighlightableString : List<HighlightableChar>
{
    private readonly string sourceString;

    public HighlightableString(string value)
    {
        sourceString = value;
        foreach (char currentChar in sourceString)
        {
            Add(new HighlightableChar(currentChar));
        }
    }

    public void Highlight(string searchString)
    {
        int index = sourceString.IndexOf(searchString);
        if (index > -1)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
            {
                if (i < index)
                {
                    this[i].IsHighlighted = false;
                }
                else if (i >= index && i < index + searchString.Length)
                {
                    this[i].IsHighlighted = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    index = sourceString.IndexOf(searchString, index + 1);
                    this[i].IsHighlighted = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (HighlightableChar c in this)
            {
                c.IsHighlighted = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a similar way I wrote the `HighlightableChar` class:

```
public class HighlightableChar : NotifyPropertyChangedImpl
{
    private readonly char sourceChar;
    private bool isHighlighted;

    public HighlightableChar(char value)
    {
        sourceChar = value;
    }

    public char SourceChar
    {
        get
        {
            return sourceChar;
        }
    }

    public bool IsHighlighted
    {
        get
        {
            return isHighlighted;
        }
        set
        {
            if (isHighlighted != value)
            {
                isHighlighted = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsHighlighted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need just two - quite simple - converters:

```
public class BoolBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;
        return boolValue ? Brushes.Yellow : Brushes.Transparent;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}

public class BoolFontWeightConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool boolValue = (bool)value;
        return boolValue ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Normal;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Running the project you will see the Window: just write a text (you can try by typing "ar") in the first TextBox and you will see some chars highlighted in the strings in the ListBox. I hope this sample can help you.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change the convertor to change the return textBlock with multiple run.

```
public class HighlightNames : IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                           var personName = ((Person)value).PersonName;

                var textBlock = new TextBlock();
                textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

                // Add logic to split the string into multiple string to split based on string to highlight. For ex in Mahesh Nagar, ar should be highlighted so string would split into two 1) Mahesh Nag 2) ar

    string toSearch = "ar";
    var regex = new Regex(toSearch);

    int currentIndex = 0;
    var matches = regex.Matches(inputString);
    for (int index = 0; index < matches.Count; index++)
    {
        Match match = matches[index];

        if (match.Index == 0)
        {
                Run run = new Run(personName.Substring(0, toSearch.Length));
                run.Background = Brushes.Aqua;;
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);
        }
        else
        {
                           textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(personName.Substring(currentIndex, match.Index - currentIndex)));                             
                Run run = new Run(personName.Substring(match.Index, toSearch.Length)
                run.Background = Brushes.Aqua;;
                textBlock.Inlines.Add(run);


        }
                }

    if (currentIndex < inputString.Length)
    {
                 textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(personName.Substring(currentIndex, inputString.Length - currentIndex))); 
    }
                 return textBlock;
            }

            public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }
```

and second in xaml define the `ContentControl` instead of `TextBlock`.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding PersonName, Converter={StaticResource colorrootnode}">
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: By changing this to a `IMultiValueConverter' you can use a secondary binding for the 'search' text and a regex to *split* the string. It's a shame that there isn't a bindable property on TextBlock that accepts a list of Runs directly.

Comment: @user1672994, your solution is good but it is not highlighting if the text appears in the beginning or middle or any where else.I have updated my question and the sample output.Please let me know that changes.Also the names can be First,Middle,Last names or it can even be more e.g. namepart1 namepart2 namepart3 namepart4 namepart5.

Comment: I have given the implementation for reference purpose. You can use Regex to find the matched/unmatched strings and add the appropriate text into run..

Comment: I have updated my answer to use Regex. Use it as a reference implementation and tailored based on your functional need.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar - does the solution helped you to fix your prob?

Comment: Hi, please check the Edit.I have posted the new screen shot for the updated answer of your's.However, thanks for the help (:

Comment: I have already changed the solution to use regex. Which will highlight search string from the input string. If your queries are resolved then can you mark the answer as answer.